# How do I properly implement a Map for Custom types using generics in nested classes

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, implementation

In short I'm trying to write an `AbstractMap` implementation and I encountered a syntax problem that I do not understand.

Consider the following two sketches (the identifiers with `My` before them are custom types).

---

**(1) Not Working:**

```
public class CustomMap extends AbstractMap<MyKey,MyValue> {
    private Set<Map.Entry<MyKey,MyValue>> data = null ;
    public static class MyMapEntry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> { 
        //...
    }
    public static class MyEntrySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
        //...
    }
    public static class MyEntrySetIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
        //...
    }
    { // initializer block
        this.data = new MyEntrySet<MyMapEntry<MyKey,MyValue>>() ;
    }
    // (constructors and methods of the Map interface)

}
```

**(2) Working:**

```
public class CustomMap extends AbstractMap<MyKey,MyValue> {
    private Set<Map.Entry<MyKey,MyValue>> data = null ;
    public static class MyMapEntry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> { 
        //...
    }
    public static class MyEntrySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
        //...
    }
    public static class MyEntrySetIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
        //...
    }
    { // initializer block
        this.data = new MyEntrySet<Map.Entry<MyKey,MyValue>>() ;
    }
    // (constructors and methods of the Map interface)

}
```

---

The only difference is in the way I instantiated `this.data` (the `Set` backing the `Map`): apparently the compiler does not accept an instance of `Map.Entry` (such as `MyMapEntry`) as the parameterized type of `MyEntrySet`.

The compiler complains about "incompatible types".

I wonder why.

Please post comments in case I need to elaborate,
TIA,

FK82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on the other answers with a simpler example.

Consider

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> objects = strings; // this is what you are doing in your constructor
objects.add("some string");
```

objects has declared that it will only contain Objects, and strings has declared that it will only contain Strings. So surely assigning strings to objects should be fine as all Strings are Objects? We're even allowed to add Strings to objects without a problem.

However, what about this situation.

```
objects.add(new Object());
```

Since objects is just strings, we are adding an Object to strings, and thus breaking its declaration that it will only contain Strings.

Comment: I understand that. It is however not an explanation but rather a restatement of the problem.

Comment: If you understand that then you should understand why the compiler complains about your assignment to this.data. The compiler cannot ensure that the this.data will only ever contain instances or subclasses of MyEntrySet<MyKey,MyValue>.

Answer (score 4):

That's why:

```
MyEntrySet<MyMapEntry<MyKey,MyValue>>() mySet = 
   new MyEntrySet<MyMapEntry<MyKey,MyValue>>();

this.data = mySet; // Imagine that this cast is possible
this.data.add(new SomeOtherMapEntry());

MyMapEntry<MyKey, MyValue> e = 
    mySet.iterator().next(); // Unexpected ClassCastException!
```

`MyEntrySet<MyMapEntry<MyKey,MyValue>>` is a `Set` that can contain only instances of `MyMapEntry<MyKey,MyValue>`. `Set<Map.Entry<MyKey,MyValue>>` can contain arbitrary instances of `Map.Entry<MyKey,MyValue>`. Cast between them would violate type safety.

Comment: How does that violate type safety if one is the interface the other implements? More to the point: the compiler says "incompatible types" and I do not understand how that makes sense in that case. After all assigning a variable to a type that is an interface and instantiating a subclass does not violate anything (e.g.: `List myList = new ArrayList();`).

Comment: @FK82: Look at the sample. Generics (when applied consistently) guarantee that you can't get `ClassCastException` in unexpected places. The conversion in question breaks this guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

It is common mistake about generics, it is conceptually difficult to adapt yourself that `List<Child>` is not assignable to `List<Parent>` , where `Child` is subtype of `Parent`.

Comment: Alright. I understood that it has to do with generics rather than something else in the language specification. Any specific reason for that restriction?

Comment: axtavt has explained the reason. Java generics are very strongly typed. I do recommend you generics tutorial, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not your fault. In the Map API

```
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

A more sophisticated version should be

```
    Set<? extends Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

So that `MyEntrySet<MyMapEntry>` could work just fine.

---

But I like the 1st version. I'm so sick of these stupid wildcards everywhere, it makes me want to puke.

There was a much better syntax, used by all research papers that Java Generics was based upon

```
    Set<+Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

Some smartass in Sun don't believe that java programmers can handle it, so we now have this much more fugly, insane syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting background. Thanks also for adding the wildcard solution.